# How can we rotate UIImageView by 360 degree using touch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5

i need a code to rotate UIImageView by 360 degree i.e. clock direction or anti clock direction depending on touch.

if user touch 90 degree angle then image should rotate 90 degree only. like i need to handle 90,180,270 and 360 degree angle.

Answer (score 0):

please find angle with the help of y2-y1/x2-x1 formula

tap the finger on screen then you can get touch point there.
so it is x2,y2

and the center of the imageview is x1,y1

on touches end put this line  in code.

```
[imageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degree*(M_PI/180.0f))];
```

it will work for sure.